# SQL total days between fields

Tags: php, mysql

to display database results on a web page i use the following. this code works just fine.  It was a test.  The date is the first field in the database.  when not using the date and trying to use the field name as below it fails to give any results

```
    DATEDIFF(NOW(), '2011-11-19') AS 'days_reg'
```

this does not work if i put in the field name for date IE:

```
    DATEDIFF(NOW(), UserAccounts.created) AS 'days_reg'
```

I get no results as if the database is not being read yet i use that field for another result and it is read and found... I am lost

Thanks John

Comment: You get no error and 0 results?  Can you output UserAccounts.Created and see if it is the expected value?

Comment: yes i also use UserAccounts.created  for another display on the page.  all 530 dated are displayed just fine on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you getting your information from?

If you have a table like this:

```
+----------+------------+
| username | reg_date   |
+----------+------------+
| user1    | 2011-11-19 |
+----------+------------+
```

You should run a SELECT query like this to get the registration date for this one person.

`SELECT username, DATEDIFF(NOW(), reg_date) AS 'days_reg' WHERE username = 'user1'`

Comment: I just used a snippet of all the code... I have a select  and multiple fields are called.  all works except that datediff.  if I use NOW() - (UserAccounts.created)  i get a crazy number ...

Comment: And that crazy number is?

Comment: (NOW() - (UserAccounts.created)) AS 'days_reg  Yields  20148881447152  for first record  20148881416158  for second and so on..

Comment: Can you print out the exact value of UserAccounts.created?

Comment: first record  1321718771 second record 1321749765  it is the date in unix time.. I can format it with the %Y-%d-%m and it will print out fine.  BUT i need to subtract it from the current date to get days registered to display

Comment: Use `FROM_UNIXTIME(UserAccounts.created)`, so: `SELECT username, DATEDIFF(NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(UserAccounts.created)) AS 'days_reg' WHERE username = 'user1'`

Comment: also  FROM_UNIXTIME(NOW())-(UserAccounts.created) AS 'days_reg'  yields no result....

Comment: `NOW()` does NOT return a UNIX timestamp, so what you are doing makes absolutely no sense. I just gave you a working solution in the comment, why are you not using it? What you just showed me is something completely different. What my query will do is get the date difference of `NOW()` and the `UserAccounts.created` UNIX timestamp converted to a date.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH... read your answer and plugged in the code and BINGO it works perfectly....